# Identify Spam from fb:comments via FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, spam, facebook-comments

I'm running an FQL query to get comments for a particular post made on a  site.

Is there a way to identify whether it has been marked as spam?

If not, I can see that the blog owner removed some comments so that they are not visible on the site. Is there a away to identify which have been "hidden/deleted" by the blog owner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the is_private attribute. It seems to be set to true when comment is marked as spam or deleted.