# Facebook Graph Api 2.1: get comments marked as spam

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spam, facebook-comments

I'm using the Facebook Graph Api v2.1 to get all comments on the posts we do on our Facebook page.  I noticed we are missing some comments because Facebook has marked them as Spam. Is there a way I can retrieve these comments too? I tried this:
[Identify Spam from fb:comments via FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301801/identify-spam-from-fbcomments-via-fql/10703237#10703237)
.. but all comments come back with is_private "false". So I take it I have to go up one level and add a property to the API call.. Searched through the maze of documentation over at Facebook, but no luck..
Here is the URL I use to get the comments:

```
/v2.1/{0}/comments?fields=id,from,message,created_time&access_token={1}
```

where `{0}` is the object id of the post and `{1}` the access token.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t think there is any way to retrieve such comments. If they have been marked as spam, FB will most likely not want them to show up anywhere outside of FB as well.

Comment: @CBroe: you would think that, but in FB frontend you do have the opportunity to view the spammified comment, like this: http://socialmediamarketingkelowna.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Facebook-censorship-how-to-find-missing-comments-that-are-Not-Spam.png
Makes me think there should also be some way to get those posts using the API...

Comment: Well the docs don’t seem to contain anything in this regard, so I doubt it is accessible via API. And just because some functionality is available through the frontend doesn’t mean the API has to provide it as well (that assumption has been proven wrong for a lot of cases in the past already). So I don’t see any way for your app to retrieve those spam comments, sorry.